# C# WinUI 3 frame navigation stack

Tags: c#, navigation, frame, winui-3

In my WinUI3 C# application I have a frame with a content page. Given that I set `IsNavigationStackEnabled` to true on the frame, I'd expect the current page to be pushed to the navigation stack when I navigate (using `MyFrame.Navigate(...)`) so I could use `MyFrame.GoBack()` to navigate back to the previous page.

However, trying to invoke `MyFrame.GoBack()` *after* navigating from one page to another always results in an exception: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'`. What's more, the `CanGoBack`-property is always `false`.

Am I missing something or is the navigation stack just not managed by the frame in WinUI3 and do I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a working sample code for `Frame` navigation. Note that there's no `IsNavigationStackEnabled` in the code. `IsNavigationStackEnabled` is `true` by default.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Column="0"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="Page1Button"
                Click="Page1Button_Click"
                Content="Page1" />
            <Button
                x:Name="Page2Button"
                Click="Page2Button_Click"
                Content="Page2" />
            <Button
                x:Name="Page3Button"
                Click="Page3Button_Click"
                Content="Page3" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="BackButton"
                Click="BackButton_Click"
                Content="Back" />
            <Button
                x:Name="NextButton"
                Click="NextButton_Click"
                Content="Next" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind NavigationLogs}" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Frames;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigateTo(typeof(Page1));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> NavigationLogs { get; } = new();

    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateBack();
    }

    private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateForward();
    }

    private void Page1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateTo(typeof(Page1));
    }

    private void Page2Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateTo(typeof(Page2));
    }

    private void Page3Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateTo(typeof(Page3));
    }

    private void NavigateTo(Type pageType)
    {
        this.NavigationFrame.Navigate(pageType);
        NavigationLogs.Add($"Navigated to {pageType}.");
    }

    private void NavigateBack()
    {
        if (this.NavigationFrame.CanGoBack is true)
        {
            this.NavigationFrame.GoBack();
            NavigationLogs.Add("Navigated back.");
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationLogs.Add("Cannot to navigate back.");
        }
    }

    private void NavigateForward()
    {
        if (this.NavigationFrame.CanGoForward is true)
        {
            this.NavigationFrame.GoForward();
            NavigationLogs.Add("Navigated forward.");
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationLogs.Add("Cannot to navigate forward.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be darned! Thanks for the working example, I have yet to figure out what you did different from me, other than the fact that you have the frame directly in the window while I have it in a page.

Comment: Follow-up: nested frames seems to have been the problem. The more you know.